# conditional formatting gets messed up in merged cells excel 2016

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I am trying to put together a sheet that shows progress in several categories with data bars like this:
[Correctly formatted cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oQrk.png)

The lower cells are the min and max values for each category and the bar uses the max value on the right as the max value for the data bar in the merged cell.
I have several groups like this with different min and max values that I want to copy and paste into other worksheets and work books.  The problem is that When I paste them, this is what happens:
[Bad formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIjZ4.png)
The data bar formatting gets messed up.

I have to go back through and reformat every merged cell and even then, it often splits merged cells and formats the data bar all wonky.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: Do you need the merged cells? You can often use align across cells to avoid them.

Comment: I will try that. Thanks.

Comment: Align across only seems to work for text.  The data bar formats correctly, but it only fills the first cell.